# Simplifying in a Implicit Differentiation Equation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I think this is really simple, but I just can't make sense of it.

How do I simplify:
y" = -3[x²y³ + x^6/y]/y^6 
to
y" = -3x²/y^7 [ y^4 + x^4] 
Specifically what happens to the 1/y such that y^3 becomes y^4?

Here is where I found this (https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080507054545AAGm961)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ y" = \dfrac{-3\left[x^2y^3 + \dfrac{x^6}{y}\right]}{y^6} = {-3\left[\dfrac{x^2y^3}{y^6} + \dfrac{x^6}{y^7}\right]}=\dfrac{-3\left[x^2y^4 + x^6\right]}{y^7}=\dfrac{-3x^2\left[y^4 + x^4\right]}{y^7}$

Comment: omg thanks!  >.< I'l make sure i never make a mistake like this again. ♥